# Generate file with types in post build from dependency types?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, prisma

I have types I want to extract from a 3rd party dependency and bring it into my source control to make it part of my own package. I'm trying to break the coupling of the 3rd party dependency so I can share my own package without carrying the other package around. I'm hoping for something like this:

```
// generate-types.ts
import { Customer } from '@prisma/client`
// How to generate Customer.ts file with properties types?

// Customer.ts
interface Customer {
  id: string;
  name: string;
}
```

I only need the types from Prisma. The types in the 3rd party dependency get generated on build, so I need to copy those types in my post build. Any ideas on how to achieve this?